# How to return value of both of the consecutive async functions in JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've recently started with web development, and am a novice in JavaScript.
I'm currently working on a Blog Project and using Firebase as the backend, and Firestore as the Database.

**PROJECT-**

using the following project structure

```
Firestore DB ->
   -Posts
       -post1
       -post2
       -post3
        ...
   -authors
       -author1
       -author2
        ..
   -subscribers
       ...
```

I'm using this function to retrieve my posts from Firestore.

```nodejs
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;  

async function getDocument(id) {
    const doc = await db.collection('Posts').doc(id).get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      return doc.data();
    }
  }

getDocument(id).then(function (data) {
  res.render('post',{ articleInfo:data} ); 
  // that send back an object containing post details
})
```

Now, from the JSON I get from the above function, I want to use the value of "Author" to get the author's details from the another collection(run another async function),
and then send this data along with the data from previous function(used to get post details) together in `res.render()`

**For example**

I make a get request for a post and get back it's details. Inside which get the author's name `"{..,"author : mike-ross",..} "` .

Now, after `.then`, I use this value to run another async function get this author's JSON from the `Authors` collection. and pass the result from both the functions together in `res.render()` to get diplayed on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have one async function that does both calls and returns an object with both results:

```js
async function getDocWithDetails (id) {
  const doc = await getDocument(id);
  const authorInfo = await getAuthorInfo(doc.author);
  return {
    doc: doc.data(),
    authorInfo: doc.data()
  }
}

getDocWithDetails(id).then((data) => {
  res.render('post', data) // has data.doc and data.authorInfo
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

But when working with firebase, we have to add '.data()' to the returned value from the get() request. 
I cannot simply type `return { doc, author }`
So when I return this, it is returning an error, as well as with this - 
`return {
doc.data(),
author.data() }
`
Please help me on how to combat this.

Comment: `{ doc: doc.data(), author: author.data() }`

Comment: updated my answer, but for future reference `{ doc, author }` is shorthand for `{ doc: doc, author: author }`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ray, you helped me a lot :) it finally works.

Answer (score 0):

Just go for it, same way you did the first half :-)

> In general *(at least at my work projects)*, it's good practice to setup multiple getters for each collection or one main getter where the collection is a secondary argument.

Here's the second variant with dynamic variant (but the first one is just as valid). Especially if you're not using [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) or [flowtype](/questions/tagged/flowtype) to typecheck what you're passing, then it's more prone to unexpected errors by passing incorrect param, I'm just lazy to write the similar function in the answer twice.

```js
const getDocumentById = async (id, collection) => {
  const doc = await db.collection(collection).doc(id).get()
  if (!doc.exists) {
   throw Error(`Doc with id "${id}" doesn't exist on collection "${collection}"`)
  }
  return doc.data()
}
```

Now that we have our generic getter setup, you just need to create a function that fetches both.

> As a precursor, I have taken some creative liberties with the answer, since the question is missing some cruicial info about documents.
> At the very least *(and if you don't you should, it's good firebase practice)* I presume you have a link to the `authorId` inside `Posts` document.

```
Posts
  -> post
    -> id
    -> authorId
    -> some_other_fields
Authors
  -> author
    -> id
    -> some_other_fields
```

With the following structure in mind, your answer will look something like this:

```js
const getAuthorByPostId = async (id) => {
  try {
    const post = await getDocumentById(id, 'Posts')
    const { authorId } = post 
    const author = await getDocumentById(authorId, 'Authors')
    // I'm not sure how your res is structured, but could look something like this
    res.render('page', { articleInfo: post, authorInfo: author })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
  }
  // in case it was unable to fetch data
  return null
}
```